# repeating a button in a php while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

The following is a markup I have for displaying my database:

```
$html = '';
$database_enquiry = tep_db_query("(relevant database enquiry in here)");
while ($database = tep_db_fetch_array($database_enquiry)){
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '      <td>'.$myV['myVariable goes here'].'</td>';
    $html .= '      <td><button id="editDriver"></button><button id="timeDriver"></button></td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';       
}

echo $html;
```

For some reason, the rows, are displaying in the loop, but the buttons are only showing up for the first row. Anyone know why?

Comment: I don't know if it solves your problem, but remember that id attributes should be unique, only used in one element for the whole page. If your code were working, you'd have many buttons with the same id.

Comment: You shouldn't use multiple ID's with the same name.

Comment: id's are all different, like i said, it prints on the first row, but after that, not at all

Comment: Is it possible that the query result, $myV, is valid only for the first instance (e.g, it is not assigned properly), therefore the code is breaking at that point? What does a View Source show about the structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs, as their name imply, should be unique to a document, you are duplicating the buttons IDs for every row.

Normaly most browsers don't make a fuss if you have dulicates (though they should), but it seems in your case, it's causing problems.

So, give your buttons unique IDs accross rows, or use classes to see if it helps:

```
$html .= '      <td><button class="editDriver"></button><button class="timeDriver"></button></td>';
```

Comment: can class be used for a jquery button?

Comment: sure: $("button.editDriver").click(function(evt){ alert("booya!"); });

Answer (score 0):

Could you write something between the button tag and add type attribute?

```
<button type="button">Something</button>
```

[ref](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There are **3 things** you need to fix/check:

- The **`id`** attribute id unique. You should not have more than one per page
- **`<tr></tr>`** tags should be inside a **`<table></table>`** element.
- Maybe your query return a single row, in which case your code is working properly.

Also, you should check the official documentation for the button element: **http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button**